# Restore (or re-add) SharePoint - 80 Website that was deleted from IIS6

Tags: iis-6, sharepoint

In the IIS Manager the website SharePoint - 80 was deleted.

What is the best way to restore the site settings?
I tried to add it manually and point at the folder doesn't seem to work, are there special settings that need to be added?

** EDIT **

I was able to get a copy of the MetaBase.xml file from IIS, can this file be replaced or the missing section just be added back in?

Comment: What version of SP?

Comment: sharepoint 2007

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I was able to figure this out using the guides listed below.

1. Restore a backup of the windows\system32\inetsrv folder
   (including the \metaback folder)
2. Copy the last working configuration file into the metaback folder.
3. Open IIS, right click on the IIS server and select backup restore
4. Load the configuration you just dropped in
5. Cross your fingers!
6. Go have a beer

http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/backing_up_and_restoring_your_iis_6_metabase

http://www.visualwin.com/IIS-Backup/